# How is layoutIfNeeded used?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

When and how is `layoutIfNeeded` used? I know that when we change the layout of a view, we can call `setNeedsLayout` to update the layout but not sure when `layoutIfNeeded` should be used.

NOTE: I have `layoutIfNeeded` used in actual code but forgot in what context it was used.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`layoutIfNeeded` forces the receiver to layout its subviews immediately if required.

Suppose you have overridden `layoutSubviews`, and UIKit feels that your view requires layout for whatever reason (e.g. you called `setNeedsLayout` when handling some user action). Then, your custom `layoutSubviews` method will be called immediately instead of when it would normally be called in the regular UIKit run loop event sequence (after event handling, but before `drawRect:`).

An example of why you might need to call `layoutIfNeeded` within a single run loop:

1. You resize a custom view containing a table view with a custom layout. `setNeedsLayout` is set so that `layoutSubviews` will be called later.
2. A controller object asks the table view to scroll to some particular cell when handling a user event.
3. Your custom view performs some custom sizing of the table view in `layoutSubviews` that changes the table view size.

The problem is when the controller asked the table view to scroll (step 2), the table view had bounds that were stale. The updated bounds would only be set on the table view later (step 3). What the controller wanted the table view to scroll to may not actually be visible after `layoutSubviews` is done. A solution then would be for the controller to call `layoutIfNeeded` in situations where it knows this might occur.

Answer (score 7):

The difference between these two methods can be now be described by referencing the update cycle.

The method setNeedsLayout for a UIView tells the system that you want it to layout and redraw that view and all of its subviews, when it is time for the update cycle. This is an asynchronous activity, because the method completes and returns immediately, but it isn’t until some later time that the layout and redraw actually happens, and you don’t know when that update cycle will be.

In contrast, the method layoutIfNeeded is a synchronous call that tells the system you want a layout and redraw of a view and its subviews, and you want it done immediately without waiting for the update cycle. When the call to this method is complete, the layout has already been adjusted and drawn based on all changes that had been noted prior to the method call.

So, stated succinctly, layoutIfNeeded says update immediately please, whereas setNeedsLayout says please update but you can wait until the next update cycle.

Answer (score -1):

> LayoutSubViews() - Don’t call directly, instead call
>   setNeedsLayout(),override if constraint base not offer expected
>   behaviour.
>
> SetNeedsLayout()- Call on main thread, it wait for next drawing cycle.
>   good for performance.
>
> LayoutIfNeeded() - Layout subviews immediately.

Answer (score -14):

setNeedsLayout actually calls layoutIfNeeded, so if your calling setNeedsDisplay there's no reason to call layoutIfNeeded.  In this way setNeedsLayout is a convenience method for calling layoutIfNeeded which does the heavy lifting.

Comment: This is not true.  setNeedsLayout will flag the view for layout which will result in layoutSubviews being called on another runloop cycle.  Calling layoutIfNeeded will result in layoutSubviews being called in the same runloop cycle.  To test this set a breakpoint in layoutSubviews and then a breakpoint on a call to setNeedsLayout.  If you advance one line then you'll notice that you don't break in layoutSubviews.  However, if you break on layoutIfNeeded and advance a line you'll notice that you WILL break in layoutSubviews before advancing.