# UIScrollView in UITableViewCell prototype scrolls only after reuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I have set up a horizontal `UIScrollView` in a `UITableViewCell` prototype in my storyboard, along with its content views. I have made use of Autolayout.

In the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I am setting the `contentSize` as well as `contentOffset` for this scrollView.

The problem arises when the cells are created for the first time. Neither does the scrollView scroll, nor is the contentOffset taking place.

However, when I scroll down a few cells (when they start getting reused), the contentOffset takes place, and the scrollView is interactive.

Since I have subclassed the `UITableViewCell`, I have tried setting the contentOffset in the `-awakeFromNib` method, to no affect. I also tried doing so in the `-tableView:willDisplayCell:` method to no avail.

What could be going wrong? Is there a workaround?

There doesn't seem to be any relevant code that I could include. Please comment if you need more info.

**EDIT**
I do not know whether this is relevant, but the Storyboard is showing a warning:
`Scroll View: Has ambiguous scrollable content width`

Comment: did you try [cell setNeedsLayout] right after creating it within cellForRowAtIndexPath method? sometimes it's helpful

Comment: @ZeMoon, We have fetch same issue with Text view. In your case may be issue with Autolayout or cell Reusability. Please remove Autolayout then after remove cell reusability with Table view. Please Tried that and let us know your comments.

Comment: @heximal You were on the right track. `[cell setNeedsLayout]` did not work, but `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because the scrollView was not being laid out after setting the `contentSize`. This would not have been a problem if the contentSize had been set properly in the storyBoard itself (still dont know how to do that).

Anyways, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, calling

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

immediately after setting the contentSize worked.

A good explanation on how this method works can be found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182945/how-is-layoutifneeded-used).