# UITableViewCell not responding to setNeedsLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableView` in Grouped format with a few cells in it. In the cells is a `UIView` to which I am adding another `UIView`. When I update the frame of the first `UIView`, it doesn't change the position of it nor the size.

The `UIViews` realign themselves correctly if the cell goes offscreen and onscreen again, so the actual transformation is being applied, it's just the re-rendering that's not happening properly.

The code for this is just in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[cell.cellMoney setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[cell.cellMoney.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

UIView *sellMoneySubView = [UIMoneyDisplay createViewWithAmount:item.min_sale_unit_price fontSize:17.0];
[cell.cellMoney setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-sellMoneySubView.frame.size.width-20, 7, sellMoneySubView.frame.size.width, sellMoneySubView.frame.size.height)];

[cell.cellMoney addSubview:sellMoneySubView];

[cell setNeedsLayout];
```

The sub `UIView` that I'm adding to the first `UIView` gets added and rendered properly, it's just the first's positioning that's gone weird.

Oh, I'm also using AutoLayout with the storyboard.

Addition: I fixed part of my problem, but the title is still valid. I also have a cell with an image that needs to be downloaded through the network, but that cell doesn't respond to any form of layout call either.

I fixed the problem with the position of the `UIView` by removing the middle view and adding straight to the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: Thanks for editing that. I completely forgot about putting the class names in code format.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this
  `[cell setNeedsLayout]`
use `[cell layoutIfNeeded]`

```
[cell.cellMoney setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[cell.cellMoney.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

UIView *sellMoneySubView = [UIMoneyDisplay createViewWithAmount:item.min_sale_unit_price fontSize:17.0];
[cell.cellMoney setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-sellMoneySubView.frame.size.width-20, 7, sellMoneySubView.frame.size.width, sellMoneySubView.frame.size.height)];

[cell.cellMoney addSubview:sellMoneySubView];

[cell layoutIfNeeded]; //use this
return cell;
```

This might helps you :)

Comment: Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182945/how-is-layoutifneeded-used?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't work either.