# Animate view height with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have view **sView** inside my ViewController. It height has constraint - I created IBOutlet for this constraint - **sViewHeightConstraint**. I want to decrease height of sView with animation.

I created function

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5.5, animations: {
                self.sViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50
            })
```

Height of view is changing but i don't see any animation. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

use `layoutIfNeeded()`

```
 view.layoutIfNeeded() // force any pending operations to finish

 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.sViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

**swift 3**

```
view.layoutIfNeeded() 
sViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { 
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
})
```

Comment: @moonvader `layoutIfNeeded` on the view force any pending operations to finish and then in the animation block capture the frame changes.

Comment: for more info. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182945/how-is-layoutifneeded-used

Answer (score 1):

In case your view updates but animation isn't working, this solution works for me.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
    self.sViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50
    self.sView.size = CGSize(width: self.sView.frame.width, height: 50)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
})
```