# Animating collection view height change (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to animate the height change for a collection view, but I can't figure out how to get the animation to work. The height changes correctly, but it happens immediately, not animated.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.collectionViewHeight.constant = 0
            }
```

I tried searching for solutions, but couldn't find anything specific to this situation. Also tried `layoutIfNeeded()` suggested here, but it didn't help: [Animate view height with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953508/animate-view-height-with-swift)

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should update the constant of the constraint outside of the animation block:

```
self.collectionViewHeight.constant = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut,   
  animations: view.layoutIfNeeded, completion: nil)
```

*(`view` is the superview of the collection view in question.)*

Comment: Thanks!! This worked! (... self.view.layoutIfNeeded() ...)