# Animate UIView width does not work

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

Try to animate the width of a `UIView` like this. But it does not do anything. Why? The commented part changes `alpha` of the view, and that works.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {

    self.constraintLookupWidth.constant = 300
    self.viewLookup.setNeedsLayout()
    //self.viewLookup.alpha = 0.2

}, completion: {complete in

    self.constraintLookupWidth.constant = 200
    self.viewLookup.setNeedsLayout()
    //self.viewLookup.alpha = 1.0
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953508/animate-view-height-with-swift/36953518#36953518

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need to integrate the call with a `layoutIfNeeded()`, this ask auto layout to force the layout right now.