# Does NSLayoutConstraint calls layoutIfNeeded or layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

Suppose I have created a subclass of `UIView` to make a custom UI component and I have another view inside my custom view.
Here's the code

```
class CustomView : UIVIew{
    private var innerView : UIView!

    convenience init(){
        self.init(frame : CGRectZero);
    }
    override init(frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame);

        self.innerView = UIView();

        /*
          * The following code is the frame I want to set
            for my innerView evertimes iOS layouts my CustomView
            by means of NSLayoutConstraint because writing 
            NSLayoutConstraint programmatically is time consuming.

          * The Question is where to put this code ?
            Inside layoutIfNeeded() or layoutSubviews
        */
        let myDesiredWidth = self.frame.size.width * 0.8;
        let myDesiredHeight = self.frame.size.height * 0.8;
        let myDesiredX : CGFloat = (self.frame.size.width - myDesireWidth) / 2
        let myDesiredY : CGFloat = (self.frame.size.height - myDesireHeight) / 2;
        let myDesireFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(myDesiredX, myDesiredY, myDesiredWidth, myDesiredHeight);

        self.innerView.frame = myDesireFrame;
    }

    override func layoutSubviews(){

    }
    override func layoutIfNeeded(){

    }
```

}

Inside my code, u can see there is innerView of type `UIView` as a private property. There is the frame for that view I want to set everytime iOS updates my CustomView's frame if someone or I add `NSLayoutConstraint` in my CustomView instance.
When `iOS` updates the `UIViewController`'s subviews by means of `NSLayoutConstraint`, which one is called, `layoutIfNeeded()` or `layoutSubviews()`?
Swift or Objective-C , it doesnt matter.

Comment: `layoutIfNeeded()` will call `layoutSubviews()` if it determines that a layout pass is necessary.  You should override `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: You will get some idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182945/how-is-layoutifneeded-used