# Centering a button in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, uikit

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to center a `UIButton` in `UIScrollView`...

```
let sv = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 600))
let b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
sv.addSubview(b)
b.center = sv.center
```

No matter what I do, the button seems to be off center. This logic works in normal `UIView`. Why doesn't it with `UIScrollView`?

Comment: why don't you just put it in the center of UIView?
it will always be in the center.

Comment: The thing is I'd need the button's y position to be after all the content in the scroll view, but still centered in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
let b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: sv.frame.size.width/2 -15, y: sv.frame.size.height/2 -15, width: 30, height: 30))
```

for your code first check value of `sv.center`, if it is OK and your UI is not updating then call `layoutIfneeded`

**Reference :** [How is layoutIfNeeded used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182945/how-is-layoutifneeded-used)